# a requirement to enter data in a field of contact, type_of_customer__c according to same field in account. I am getting nullpointerexception in line6

Tags: null-pointer

```java
public class contactTriggerHandler {
    
    public void beforeInsert(Map<ID,contact> newMap)
    {
        set<ID> s= new set<ID>();
        **for(contact con:newMap.values())**
        {
            if(con.accountId!=null)
            s.add(con.accountID);
        }
        Map<Id,Account> accMap=new Map<Id,Account>([select id,type_of_customer__c from account where id IN :s AND type_of_customer__c!=null]);
        for(contact c:newMap.values())
        {
            if(c.type_of_customer__c==null)
            {
                if(!accMap.containsKey(c.accountID))
                    c.addError('Value cannot be null');
                else
                    c.type_of_customer__c=String.valueOf(accMap.get(c.accountID));   
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is to be believed, then this is a simple issue.

`trigger.newMap` is null in `before insert`. So you're passing in a null value to the `beforeInsert()` method, and getting a null pointer exception when you try to use it.

Your trigger needs to change so that it passes `trigger.new` into this method.
Your method needs to change so that it accepts (and uses) a `List<Contact>` instead of a map.